# DB raw use eloquent relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

registrant

```
id
branch_id
name
```

branch

```
id
branch_code
```

employee

```
id
registrant_id
name
status
```

i want to "count" status that is "Actived" by branch, and do clustering by branch_code.
I've made code like this, it didn't work. maybe friends here can handle it. thanks.

```
Employee::where('status', 'Actifed')
          ->whereRelation('registrant.branch', 'branch_code', $user->branch->branch_code)
          ->select(DB::raw('count(status) as count, registrant.branch.branch_code'))
          ->groupBy('registrant.branch.branch_code')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `withCount()` and also have your conditions,

i can't what actually your query must do, but this works to get counts with conditions.

```
Model::withCount(['relation' => function($q){
 $q->where('status','=','active');
]);
```